# polymer-textarea doesn't appear when it seems to me it should

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-starter-kit

This is the code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">

<dom-module id="journal-entry">
  <template>
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Choose tag">
        <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{journal_tags}}">
                <paper-item>
                    {{item.tag}}
                </paper-item>
            </template>
        </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
    <paper-textarea label="journal_entry_text_area">
    </paper-textarea>
  </template>
  <script>
      (function() {
        'use strict';

    Polymer({
      is: 'journal-entry',
        ready : function(){
            this.journal_tags=[
                {tag:'meeting'},
                {tag:'payment'},
                {tag:'general_message'}
            ];
        }
        });
  })();
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

I am expecting for the paper-textarea item to appear, but it doesn't. Only the dropdown shows up in testing.

One idea that I have is that it may not be imported properly, but the import for paper-input is all that I have found in the documentation.

Another idea that I have is that mabe I should have  defined some width and height styling for the paper-textarea item? But that doesn't show up in the documentation either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
```

should be changed to

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-input/paper-textarea.html">
```